# calendar same as given image in objective c only not in swift language

Tags: objective-c, iphone

i want to make calendar like given below image perfect.so that can  any one help me to solve my issue. I have visited this site for reference  but i don't get perfect match the sites are...

```
1)https://www.cocoacontrols.com
2)code 4 app
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe because you would have to do it yourself? Plus "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Comment: i have try a lot  if u have answer then help me  otherwise no issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[PDTSimpleCalendar](https://github.com/jivesoftware/PDTSimpleCalendar) is a close framework to what you're looking for, but if you want exact one, you'll have to write it yourself ;)

Answer (score -2):

Try these one.

https://github.com/nopshusang/SACalendar

It will help you.

Comment: its not working as what i expect

Comment: you have make it custom with the help of SACalender, you have to give effort for change in it. I wish, you can do it.